# Can't get login feature to work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently learning PHP and am creating a small CMS feature that includes a login area. I have used the code below which includes an include header file that contains the doctype/head info and the opening  tag. It also includes the header content. I also have a connection file for connecting to the db.

My header include code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php echo $pagetitle ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/app.css">
<style>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800); @import url (http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon:100,200,300,400);</style>

<script src="../javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="subHeader">
<div class="row">
    <div class="four columns logo">
    <a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="eight columns navigation right">
    <ul class="navigationMain">
    <li class="<?php if($navcurrent == "home"){echo "navigationActive";} ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($navcurrent == "services"){echo "navigationActive";} ?>"><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($navcurrent == "work"){echo "navigationActive";} ?>"><a href="gallery.php">Recent Work</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($navcurrent == "about"){echo "navigationActive";} ?>"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($navcurrent == "contact"){echo "navigationActive";} ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

 <div class="twelve columns titlesection">
 <h2><?php echo $headTitle ?></h2>
 <h4><?php echo $headsubTitle ?></h4>
 </div>

 </div><!--End Feature Row-->
 </div><!--End Feature-->

 <div class="underbar">
<div class="bordertriangle"></div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="eight columns">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="three columns right socialcontainer">
        <ul class="socialicons">
        <li><a><img id="linkedinIcon" src="../images/socialli.png" alt="linkedin icon" /></a></li>
        <li><a><img id="twitterIcon" src="../images/socialtw.png" alt="twitter icon" /></a></li>
        <li><a><img id="facebookIcon" src="../images/socialfb.png" alt="facebook icon" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

When I open the admin page, the username password form, header and footer appear as they should. If I test the errors, they return as they should. However, when I successfully log in using a valid username and password, no content appears except the what is included in the header file. Can anyone point me in the direction of what i might be doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. I am a relative noob to PHP...

```
<?php 
$pagetitle = "Admin";
$navcurrent = "home";
$headTitle = "ADMIN AREA";
$headsubTitle = "SITE ADMINISTRATION AREA";
include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('../includes/headeradmin.php');


if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
echo('Successfully Logged In');
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)){

            $error = 'An Error Has Occurred - All Fields Are Required';

            }
            else{
            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?');    

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

                header('location: index.php');
                exit(); 
                }
                else{

                $error = 'The username/password you entered was incorrect - Please try again';
                    }
                }
        }
    ?>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="four columns centered">

    <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <h5 style="color: #e63333;"><?php echo $error; ?></h5>
    <br />
    <br />

    <?php   } ?>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit"  value="Login" />
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you log in successfully you're only echoing one line after the header. If there's a problem in the header that one line might not display. Since you haven't posted the header it's not possible to say much more.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick response. I echoed here to keep it simple. I actually have a form where the echo('successful login'); is above. Removed the header and broke the html down to the bare bones and it still does nothing but show a blank page.

Comment: what you see when you successfully login?

Comment: why I can't see `session_start():`? It should be at top of every page. I think that's why ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `header('location: index.php');` line if you've already output content (i.e - html code) to the browser when you included the header in this line `include_once('../includes/headeradmin.php');`

read the documentation of [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) - *Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP*

you need to redirect the user with the header() function before you output the head html of the admin page

Comment: Thanks for that. Problem still occurs when I remove the include header file. I'm new to PHP so any recommendations as to what I can do here would be appreciated.

Comment: OK Thanks. I kind of understand how header() works but not entirely. Think i'm just going to scrap the project until I can get my head around it or find an example that I can learn from. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2145682 - If you still get the error "header already sent" than try to open the file in notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF8 WITHOUT BOM